# Cannot access MySQL from Python using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, cloud, virtual-machine

I'm trying to deploy an application on a DigitalOcean droplet, the application requires Python 3.8 and MySQL which I installed both.

The server uses Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Python 3.8.10.

I am using SQLAlchemy as my ORM and `mysqlconnector` as the driver, it works well on my local machine.

The code that fails is this:

```py
class Database:
    DB_USER = os.environ['DB_USER']
    DB_PASSWORD = os.environ['DB_PASSWORD']
    DB_HOST = os.environ['DB_HOST']
    DB_NAME = os.environ['DB_NAME']

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(
            'mysql+mysqlconnector://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(
                self.DB_USER, self.DB_PASSWORD, self.DB_HOST, self.DB_NAME))

# This uses the engine
        self.create_tables()
```

On the server I get the following traceback when running this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 232, in _open_connection
    self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'or'@'localhost' to database 'renko'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 761, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 142, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 272, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1003, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 234, in _open_connection
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'or'@'localhost' to database 'renko'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sniper/main.py", line 72, in <module>
    database = Database()
  File "/root/sniper/sniper/utils/database.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.create_strategies_table()
  File "/root/sniper/sniper/utils/database.py", line 47, in create_strategies_table
    meta.create_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4744, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3078, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2994, in begin
    conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3166, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3245, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3215, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2068, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3212, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 761, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 142, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 272, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1003, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 234, in _open_connection
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(msg=exc.msg, errno=exc.errno,
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'or'@'localhost' to database 'renko'
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

For some reason I am denied access from Python but I can login via `sudo mysql -u root -p` with no errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What grants does the user "or" have ?

Comment: Seems like this was the issue, I've used this to solve it `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'abcd'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`, thanks very much!